# Issues running/debugging mapbox android code examples

Tags: mapbox-android

I am trying to get started with mapbox android and can't get any of the example projects to work.

My problem is with the imports

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;
```

I get I "cannot resolve symbol annotation", "cannot resolve symbol v7" and "cannot resolve symbol mapboxandroiddemo".

I feel like this is some android problem that I am just not understanding correctly so if anyone has some insight that would be amazing. I have tried taking out some code and using the recommended bug fixes but all that has done is break my project.

Here is the entire MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.mapboxtut;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.FeatureCollection;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.SymbolLayer;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.utils.BitmapUtils;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.get;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconImage;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.textAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.textField;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.textIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.textOffset;

/**
 * Use the {@link MapView#addOnStyleImageMissingListener(MapView.OnStyleImageMissingListener)}
 * to handle the situation where a SymbolLayer tries using a missing image as an icon. If an icon-image
 * cannot be found in a map style, a custom image can be provided to the map via
 * the listener.
 */
public class MissingIconActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ICON_SOURCE_ID = "ICON_SOURCE_ID";
    private static final String ICON_LAYER_ID = "ICON_LAYER_ID";
    private static final String PROFILE_NAME = "PROFILE_NAME";
    private static final String CARLOS = "Carlos";
    private static final String ANTONY = "Antony";
    private static final String MARIA = "Maria";
    private static final String LUCIANA = "Luciana";
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
// object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

// This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_styles_missing_icon);

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

// Add Features which represent the location of each profile photo SymbolLayer icon
                Feature carlosFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(-7.9760742,
                        41.2778064));
                carlosFeature.addStringProperty(PROFILE_NAME, CARLOS);

                Feature antonyFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(-8.0639648,
                        37.5445773));
                antonyFeature.addStringProperty(PROFILE_NAME, ANTONY);

                Feature mariaFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(-9.1845703,
                        38.9764924));
                mariaFeature.addStringProperty(PROFILE_NAME, MARIA);

                Feature lucianaFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(-7.5146484,
                        40.2459915));
                lucianaFeature.addStringProperty(PROFILE_NAME, LUCIANA);

// Use a URL to build and add a Style object to the map. Then add a source to the Style.
                mapboxMap.setStyle(
                        new Style.Builder().fromUrl(Style.LIGHT)
                                .withSource(new GeoJsonSource(ICON_SOURCE_ID,
                                        FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(new Feature[] {
                                                carlosFeature,
                                                antonyFeature,
                                                mariaFeature,
                                                lucianaFeature}))),
                        new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                                MissingIconActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

// Add a SymbolLayer to the style. iconImage is set to a value that will
// be used later in the addOnStyleImageMissingListener below
                                style.addLayer(new SymbolLayer(ICON_LAYER_ID, ICON_SOURCE_ID).withProperties(
                                        iconImage(get(PROFILE_NAME)),
                                        iconIgnorePlacement(true),
                                        iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                        textField(get(PROFILE_NAME)),
                                        textIgnorePlacement(true),
                                        textAllowOverlap(true),
                                        textOffset(new Float[] {0f, 2f})
                                ));
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

// Use the listener to match the id with the appropriate person. The correct profile photo is
// given to the map during "runtime".
        mapView.addOnStyleImageMissingListener(new MapView.OnStyleImageMissingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleImageMissing(@NonNull String id) {
                switch (id) {
                    case CARLOS:
                        addImage(id, R.drawable.carlos);
                        break;
                    case ANTONY:
                        addImage(id, R.drawable.antony);
                        break;
                    case MARIA:
                        addImage(id, R.drawable.maria);
                        break;
                    case LUCIANA:
                        addImage(id, R.drawable.luciana);
                        break;
                    default:
                        addImage(id, R.drawable.carlos);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addImage(String id, int drawableImage) {
        Style style = mapboxMap.getStyle();
        if (style != null) {
            style.addImageAsync(id, BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(drawableImage)));
        }
    }

    // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project, rebuilding it, and invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: No luck. Getting the same errors.